# What is the "Task Based Asynchronous Pattern in Unity"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the parse database for the first time, and I am confused about the "Task Based Asynchronous Pattern"?

Comment: TAP only exists in .net framework > 4.5 or mono > 3. Unity uses mono 2. So the answer is, that it does not exist.

Comment: Despite the mono limitations, a plugin can use  newer features by rebuilding the dll with new settings for older mono version. Parse does make use of Task class in its API, it is the base of it actually.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in Unity3D you should use thing called "Coroutine". Let's say we are waiting for db to be parsed:

1) We need to implement some kind of "heart beat" method for db parsing:

```
void WaitingForParsing() {
  while (isDbParsed) {
    isDbParsed = ProcessAnotherChunkOfData();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1);
  }
}
```

2) When you start DB parsing just call this:

```
StartCoroutine("WaitingForParsing");
```

3) Now your game will continue working(or showing some activity, progress bar etc.) while your DB is being parsed. Your WaitingForParsing() method will be called each frame, but WaitForSeconds suspends its running for given seconds.

You can also call WaitingForParsing() directly in your Update() method like this:

```
// instead of using StartCoroutine("WaitingForParsing")
void Update() {
    WaitingForParsing();
}
```